# How To Change Some attribute of One Input Onchange Selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

There is a selectbox. and a textbox with specific pattern for Hostname. and i am thinking about how to use of this textbox enable to change attribute on change of selectbox. in this case when the Mx selected in my selectbox i would like to change the pattern and placeholder and title change to IP Address format and Conversely to Hostname when Ns select. it is work for Ns at the present.

is there a way to do this ?
Here is my code :

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form>


<select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="MX">MX </option><!---pattern : -(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) Title:Wrong Ip Placeholder: IP address-->
  </select>
  
<br/>
 
<input type="text"  placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>
  
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this (uses jQuery):

```js
$(function(){
  $('select[name=type]').change(function(){
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>
  
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: there's a problem. when i select somthing in textbox. it is run on all class that named : to_validate. how to change the code to closest class with this name?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to give your inputs names. I will update my answer with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
 var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
 var text = document.getElementById('myInputText');
 swicth(select.value){
  case 'Record':
      text.setAttribute('placeholder',' you placeholder');
      text.setAttribute('pattern','you pattern');
      break;
  case 'NS':
      text.setAttribute('placeholder',' you placeholder');
      text.setAttribute('pattern','you pattern');
      break;
  case 'MX':
      text.setAttribute('placeholder',' you placeholder');
      text.setAttribute('pattern','you pattern');
      break;
 }
}


</script>

 <form>


  <select name="type" class="minimal" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="MX">MX </option><!---pattern : -(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) Title:Wrong Ip Placeholder: IP address-->
  </select>

  <br/>

 <input type="text" id="myInputText" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>


 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try this code

Answer (score -1):

This might help you .

```js
function changePlaceHolder(value) {

    if (value === "MX") {

        document.getElementById("wrongHost").setAttribute("placeholder", "IP address");
        document.getElementById("wrongHost").setAttribute("pattern", "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])");
        document.getElementById("wrongHost").setAttribute("title", "Wrong Ip");
    } else {
        // do something else 
    }

}
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form>


<select name="type" class="minimal" onchange="changePlaceHolder(this.value);">
    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="MX">MX </option><!---pattern : -(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) Title:Wrong Ip Placeholder: IP address-->
  </select>
  
<br/>
 
<input type="text" id="wrongHost"  placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>
  
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```